# Run Spring Boot Application in JetBrain Fleet with Environment Variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, environment-variables, jetbrains-fleet

I am trying to run my spring boot application on new JetBrain Fleet IDE, but I could not find easily a way to do that.

In the [documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/run-configs.html#reference) , the JetBrain said:

> An object that specifies custom environment variables. To define an environment variable, add a property, where the key is the variable name and the value is the value of the variable, for example:

```
"environment": {
    "TEMP_DIR": "/home/user/temp",
    "GENERATE_RANDOM_PASSWORD": "true"
}
```

But, they do not show where this "environment" object goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After try a lot, I found a solution:

- Run ->  Create a run configuration in run.json ...
- Add a "configurations", then type "gradle" (to Fleet autocomplete it).
- In "tasks" list, type "bootRun".
- And, at last, incluse the environment object with your variables values.

The final run.json file should stay like this:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "run app",
      "type": "gradle",
      "tasks": [
        "bootRun"
      ],
      "environment": {
        "DATABASE_URL" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test",
        "DATABASE_USER" : "Postgres",
        "DATABASE_PASSWORD" : "Postgres"
      },
    }
  ],

}
```

- Now, go to "Run" again and will appear a option "run app" to execute your application using environment variable.

[image]